# ConnectionRefusedError in Robot Framework: why does target machine actively refuse it?

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, imap

Say my email address is: `geode@blahemail.com`. The `blahemail` is a google mail. I mean, it is powered by Gmail. I am trying to connect to it using `Robot Framework` in `Pycharm` and `ImapLibrary`. So far, I have tried these:

```
Open Mailbox   host = imap.gmail.com    user = user    password = pass     port = 993
```

and

```
Open Mailbox    host = imap.blahemail.com    user = user    password = pass     port = 993
```

I have also tried `ImapLibrary2`. In all cases, I get this error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check your firewall or ask your admin to check it.  It may be blocked from where you're attempting to run your code.

Comment: @Max Thank you, but it didn't help :(